# Customize Angular-CLI to modify relative paths at build time

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI to build my Angular 4 project. I have a requirement to run the application

1. as a standalone application
2. as an application embedded in a portal page

The application runs well as a standalone app.

When embedded in a portal whose static content is served from a CDN, the resources that are loaded using relative URLs do not get loaded as they are nested under a different root directory under the CDN.

e.g. In my standalone app, I have a background image that I refer in my scss file as background: url('/assets/images/bg.jpg'). However, when embedded in portal, the relative URL is **/cdn/app**/assets/images/bg.jpg.

Is there a way to change the relative URLs used in SCSS and HTMLs as part of **ng build** ? Can I define a variable that holds my CDN path and Angular-CLI replaces the variable with the actual value at build time?

e.g.

*background: url('$cdnAppRoot/assets/images/bg.jpg');*

replaced with

*background: url('/cdn/app/assets/images/bg.jpg')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build for production you can add the
[deploy-url](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) param to change where the assets should be read from.

```
ng build -d /cdn/app
```

I suggest adding a new npm script called `prod` to make this easier

```
{
   "scripts: {
     // Other npm scripts
     "prod": "ng build -d /cdn/app"
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you.